# How do I get the text

Tags: php

```
    </script></form>
<div id='dle-content'><div class="news" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
        <div class="news_header">

        <div class="title_right" >
        <div class="rating">
        <div class="rat_col_new" style="text-align:right" itemscope  style="display:none;">1</span></span></div>
        <ul class="unit-rating">
        <li class="current-rating" style="width:78%;">78</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Мистика
Приключения
Ужасы

MyCode PHP
How to use it ?

elements that have the specified attribute and it starts with a certain value.
    [attribute$=value]  Matches elements that have the specified attribute and it ends with a certain value.
    [attribute*=value]  Matches elements that have the specified attribute and it contains a certain value.

Comment: You could take a look at [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What php lib do you use? Where is your code? Why are you mixing html and php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are running it in a loop? (with the $i) If you replace it with the index of the targeted elements, you get the one you want (i guess you want the first)

```
echo $htmlParser->find("/div#dle-content/div.news/div.news_header/div.title_left/a[href]", 0)->plaintext;
```